# Can gateway serve as a dispatcher?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a very simple example of syncrhronized communication:

```
                        gateway -> router -> channel1
                                          -> channel2
                                          -> channelx
```

Here is my definition:

```
<si:channel id="sendToChannel"/>

<si:gateway id="sender" 
    service-interface="com.messaging.MessageGateway" 
    default-request-channel="sendToChannel"/>


<si:router id="messageRouter"  
    input-channel="sendToChannel" >
    <bean class="com.messaging.MessageRouter"/>  
</si:router>
```

The router is defined as follows:

```
public class MessageRouter {

 /** Route messages on the basis of message DESTINATION. */
public String routeMessage(Message<?>  message) {
    if (message.getDestination().equals("channel1")) {
        return "channel1";
 ...
```

Why do I get this exception? Does it mean a geteway cannot be a dispatcher to a DirectChannel sendToChannel?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel sendToChannel.
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:82) ~[spring-integration-core-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
at  
... 77 common frames omitted
```

UPDATE: More information added

The messages I am sending contains the headers with source/destination/message type information as well as a payload that can be either a map or an empty string.

My gateway interface looks as follows:

```
public interface MessageGateway {

public static final String EMPTY = "'EMPTY_PARAMS'"; 

@Gateway 
public void sendMessage(
        @Headers Map<String, Object> headers, 
        @Payload Map<MessageParameter,String> hm);

/** Send a message with empty payload. */
@Gateway 
@Payload(EMPTY)
public void sendMessage(@Headers Map<String, Object> headers);

@Gateway 
public void sendRawMessage(Message<?> message);
```

Comment: Before I provide you an answer, please show more info: 1) how does your gateway interface looks? 2) What is the **Message** object in your routeMessage parameter? 3) IF your routing logic is so simple, may be it would be enough to cinfigure some SpEL: `expression="payload.destination"`. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to send a message before the context is fully wired up - such as in an init (or `@PostConstruct`) method? Turn on DEBUG logging, you should see `Adding {router:messageRouter} as a subscriber to the 'sendToChannel' channel`.

Comment: I do not see this in a log. The gateway is called in a constructor that is injected by Spring. Maybe this is not allowed for messages to be sent so early ?

Comment: In general, yes. it is bad idea. If you want to send a message from application start up you should use <event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="contextStartedChannel" event-ypes="org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent">.

Comment: Please put the answer to this question so that I could accept it.